# How can I clear my Visual Studio Code Suggestions Cache?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I wrote the word 'length' wrong once while developing a project and since then the suggestion keeps popping up and I need to delete it because sometimes by mistake when I autocomplete code I forget. I'v been searching the whole web for a solution, or a file where IntelliSense stores all the cached suggestions but have been unable to find anything. Does anyone know how to reset the cache or delete this suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

You could disable word based suggestions in general by adding

```json
"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false
```

to your `settings.json`. An overview of intellisense settings can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_settings).

Have you tried to **clear** the **editor history** and **command history**?
To do so:

1. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. type command *Clear Editor History* or *Clear Command History*
3. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Yeah I thought about that but I actually like them, I just need to erase the one wrong suggestion.

Comment: Found a solution yet? Mine kept suggesting some other stuff and I can't clear them...

Answer (score 1):

I found no way to do it via a command in VS Code.
The only way to get rid of this history is to delete the file 'state.vscdb' in your workspace storage cache. It's located in the VS Code cache files.
The path should look like this :
"C:\Users<user_name>\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\db095ee7ecde84a0076437e38ad52a3f"